# Can't execute simple Shell Script/Commonads with exec

Tags: c++, shell, exec

I designed a GUI with Qt5 and with the click of a button I want to start a python software. At first it tried writing a simple shell script which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Printrun
python pronterface.py
```

The script works fine when executed directly in the shell but now i want a c++ code that execute the script. I already found some useful stuff here, but i cant seem to get it to work on my project. Maybe it is because I'm running the code from Qt?

Here is the code:

```
execlp("home/user/", "./my_shell_script.sh", (char *)0);
```

and

```
execlp("home/user/Printrun", "python pronterface.py", (char *)0);
```

both dont return any errors but dont seem to work.

I am sorry if I am missing something obvious I pretty new to stuff like this.

EDIT: I also tried system() with no success and i read that exec is a much cleaner solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the specifications of `execlp()`.  The first argument, sometimes documented as `path` (but more often so for different exec functions), is expected to be a path all the way to the executable, not stopping short at the directory containing it.  The variable arguments then designate all elements to be provided as process's `argv` vector, including the zero<sup>th</sup>, which conventionally names the program being executed.  Thus:

```
execlp("home/user/my_shell_script.sh", "my_shell_script.sh", (char *)0);
```

Note, however, that when the path you give contains any slash characters, as yours does, `execlp()` is functionally equivalent to `execl()`.

Moreover, your python example (at least) seems to assume, incorrectly, that the first argument gives the initial *working directory* for the process.  If you want to change the working directory then you must do so manually.  For example,

```
chdir("home/user/Printrun");
execlp("python", "pronterface.py", (char *)0);
```

Furthermore, do be sure to check function return values for errors, and to handle them appropriately (not demonstrated above), though in the case of exec-family functions, returning at all indicates an error.

In that light however, you should recognize that if you're using this in the handler function for a GUI widget then you have a potential problem.  Very likely in that case you want to `fork()` first, so that the new process runs alongside the GUI instead of replacing it, or to use `system()` instead, which handles all the forking, execing, and waiting for you.  Note also that unlike the exec functions, `system()` runs your command via a shell.  For example, then:

```
system("cd ~/Printrun; python pronterface.py");
```

Comment: Thanks for all your tips. You helped me a lot. This is a wunderful community